# How to inverse inline function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

If I have anonymous function, for example:

```
a=3;
b=4;
y = @(x) (x)./(a+b+x);
```

So I easily can find a for x=4, but how can I find an x that will give me y=0.4? I actual looking for an easy way to have x(y) instead of y(x).

Comment: Does it specifically need to be an inline function that you want to invert?

Comment: I can use an external file YfromX.m with:
function [ Y ] = YfromX( X )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trivial approach is to use a numeric algorithm to find the zero of `y(x) - 0.4`:

```
target = 0.4;
x = fzero(@(x) y(x)-target, 0)
```

Now, `x` is `4.6667` and `y(x)` returns `0.4`.

Note that this is an easy approach, but it is not cheap computationally. Also, you need a suitable start point, which here I've set to `0`. If your function has multiple points where it reaches `0.4`, then you will get the one closest to this start point.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use MATLAB's interpolation (1D) function `interp1`, but this works on your function for parameter values that ensure `y(x)` is a **non-decreasing function**.

```
step = .01;                  % Control precision (smaller = more precise)
Xmax = 50;                   % Largest x of interest
X = [0:step:Xmax]'; 
Y = y(X);                    % Generate discrete approximation of function
yinvh=@(L) interp1(Y,X,L);

Targets = [0.25 0.4 0.75]';
yinvh(Targets)
```

This matches the results from [Cris Luengo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485730/8239061).

```
>> yinvh(Targets)'
ans =
    2.3333    4.6667   21.0000
```

[image: Illustration of inverse function]

```
figure, hold on, box on
plot(X,y(X))
plot(zeros(3,1),Targets,'rx')
plot(yinvh(Targets),zeros(3,1),'rx')
for k = 1:length(Targets)
    plot([0; yinvh(Targets(k))],Targets(k)*ones(2,1),'k--')
    plot(yinvh(Targets(k))*ones(2,1),[0 Targets(k)],'k--')
end
```